# Linked List creating a new pointer to add value but not working

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, linked-list, addition

```
void List::add_item(double new_value)
{
    if (list == nullptr)
    {
        list = new ValueList;
        list->value = new_value;
        list->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        ValueList* track = list;
        while (track != nullptr)
        {
            track = track->next;
        }
        track = new ValueList;
        track->value = new_value;
        track->next = nullptr;
    }
    size += 1;
}
```

With the following code above I'm trying to add a new value into the linked list by looping through the linked list until it reaches the end of the list and then create a dynamic variable to store that value in the linked list.

However I don't understand why it is not doing so when I output the linked list. It is only showing the last item in the list. Does this mean that track is actually pointing to list and when I loop through such as track = track->next, then list also changes? Which doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: Yes, it's not working, and it is very easy to understand why it's not working simply by observing the simple fact that there is no line of code, anywhere, that sets the `next` pointer of the last node in the original linked list to point to the new node. You `new` the next value, in the `else` part, that's correct? But where's the code that sets the last node's `next` pointer to the `new`ed node? P.S. This operation shouldn't take more than four or five lines of code, and without using any `if` statement. This just unnecessarily complicates it.

Comment: I'm thinking that the next value is already tracker so I'm directly making the change to next itself. My thinking is that if list == nullptr and changes can be made to that why not when track == nullptr as well? I'm still digesting linked list implementation

Comment: That's not how it works. If you take an apple from your left pocket, put it on your table, and cut it with a knife, you do not end up with a sliced apple in your left pocket. If you copy a `nullptr` into a variable, then set this variable to something else, wherever you copied the variable from does not also become that something else. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: oohhhh I see what you mean. If I'm understanding this correctly It's because track is a variable, so when I set it equal to new VariableList, that means that it detaches itself from the linked list that I set it to track. That's why the linked list is not connecting to new values?

Comment: @swittuh you can greatly simplify this code, to have the kind of semantics you were originally envisioned. You just need to use an extra level of pointer indirection, eg: `void List::add_item(double new_value) { ValueList** track = &list; while (*track != nullptr) { track = &((*track)->next); } *track = new ValueList{new_value, nullptr}; size += 1; }`

Comment: It was never attached to anything in the first place. Each variable is a distinct object of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing by the last element. You should in reality check if next element is `nullptr`, not if the element you are on is `nullptr`.

```
while (track != nullptr)
{
   track = track->next;
}
```

should be:

```
while (track->next != nullptr)
{
   track = track->next;
}

track->next = new ValueList;
track->next->value = new_value;
track->next->next = nullptr;
```